# Angular: Filter to limit words by spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still very much learning JS/Angular, so please be easy :)

I am trying to create a limitTo filter on certain data. This is a string of space-seperated contents, such as: `$scope.data = 'foo bar data new code';`

I'd like the user to be able to limit this to a certain number of words.
Let us say they choose "2", they would input "2", and the output would be *"foo bar"*.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input ng-model="quantity">
<p>{{name| spaced:quantity}}</p>
</body>
```

The *spaced* filter would hence split by space, and print only the desired number of words that the user has input, or *quantity*.

I know I need to create a filter for spacing, but am lost on how to start. Here's the attempt so far: https://jsfiddle.net/nick_1002/fk2qvmrs/3/

Many thanks!

Comment: the question is not clear.. please be elaborative

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it a little more clear in an edit just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to return a function in the filter.

That function needs to return the filtered output.

The function would split the string into an array of words, then reduce the size of array to word limit size, and join the array to return the new string or return the original if limit not set

```
angular.module('filters', []).
filter('spaced', function() {
  // return the function that does the filtering
  return function(str, limit) {
    if (limit) {
      return str.split(' ').splice(0, limit).join(' ');
    } else {
      // if limit not set or is zero return original string
      return str;
    }
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fk2qvmrs/6/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <input type="number" ng-model="spaceLimit" />
    <h2>{{data | spaceFilter:" ": spaceLimit}}</h2>

</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = 'foo bar data new code';
  $scope.spaceLimit = 3;

});


app.filter('spaceFilter', function() {
  return function(str,filterOn,limit) {
    if (limit) {
      return str.substring(0, str.split(filterOn, limit).join(filterOn).length);
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this